How to add CSS to a page created in Sitecore XP?
Where can I put CSS in Sitecore XP? Currently, it is hardcoded and stored in the wwwroot folder. I uploaded it to the media library part of Sitecore but can't use it. When I use Sitecore experience editor, the content is presented without CSS, whereas using site definition CSS works perfectly. Please let me know if there are any resources I can refer to.
Here is my site when displayed using experience editor

Here is my site when displayed using site definition (picking up css from wwwroot folder, css folder published from solution)

CSS file path


Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange!!! Can you please add more details regarding where you are hardcoding css path in order to understand the issue better and provide the appropriate solution.

Hello, thank you for your help. I am a newbie and am now learning Sitecore, thus I am not sure how to use CSS with Sitecore. My CSS is currently located in the wwwroot folder on C Drive. I uploaded CSS to Sitecore's Media Libraries section but don't know how to use it; I tried exploring the internet but it didn't help.

You can provide css path inside the layout file. Have you created the layout inside your solution?

Yes, I have done it that way. However, while using the Sitecore Experience editor, the content is rendered without the use of CSS. Please see the images in the updated question.

Can you check the path is relative inside the layout file and also check on the console of the experience editor are you getting any error.

If the path is relative can you make that absolute by adding / at the starting of the css path.

Thank you, Sir. It finally worked. Is this the standard approach for adding CSS to Sitecore?

Glad to hear that. I have added my answer below on how to the CSS/JS path inside the layout file in Sitecore.

Since the css is not loading inside experience editor whereas it is loading from site context, you can make sure the css path is not relative inside the layout file and configured with absolute path as below.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css"/>

You can also add the tlide(~) sign inside the path, in order to make sure it loads the path from wwwroot folder.
Hope this helps!!!

Thank you so much, Sir.
